# Getting The Location Of A Control Relative To The Entire Screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, location

Let's say I have a Control and its location is relative to its parent.  If its embedded many times and is the great great great grandchild of the main form, how can I determine what its location is on my entire screen, not just its location in the immediate parent?  This is for the purpose of printing a particular Control via a screenshot (since for some controls the DrawToBitmap doesn't work properly).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You're looking for the [`PointToScreen` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx):

```
Point location = someControl.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

Comment: Note that PointToScreen takes _client area_ coordinates, so using this code on a Form for instance would not give the correct result.

Comment: @rymdsmurf not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you use it on a `Form` (like `myForm.PointToScreen`) and you have the right coordinates (from `control.Location`) it will give you the right coordinates on the screen.

Comment: As a note: make sure your screens are scaled to 100% to get correct values. Mine was 125% and I was getting wrong values.

Comment: How to take scaling into consideration?

Comment: @pookie you can get a Graphics object (Dim g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()) and use (g.DpiX / 96) to get the scaling factor. It ill be 1 for 100% and 1.5 for 150%.