# Get coordinates of ListView items' subitems relative to the Form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, coordinates

I have a `ListView` with 4 items, and 3 subitems in each item.

Now, for example, I'd want to get the coordinates(position) relative to the `Form` for item 2, subitem 2.

How can I do it?

Comment: x and y yes. For the Form.

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998076/getting-the-location-of-a-control-relative-to-the-entire-screen

Comment: With that I can only get list.PointToScreen(Point.Empty); I want to get like list.Items[1].SubItems[1].PointToScreen(Point.Empty); (but that gives errors)

Comment: Yes, looks like [SubItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a control, so it does not have `PointToScreen` method.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.bounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how to use that... Maybe an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `Bounds` property of a `ListViewSubItem`. Here is a simple usage of the property:

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var bound = listView1.Items[1].SubItems[1].Bounds;

    if (e.X > bound.Left && e.X < bound.Right && e.Y > bound.Top && e.Y < bound.Bottom)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helps :)

Comment: You can also use " bound.Contains (e.Location) " for a more compact code.