# Position of curson in clickevent

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to fetch the position of Control in which click event is performed

for this I have tried following code

```
Xpos = Cursor.Position.X;
Ypos = Cursor.Position.Y;
```

but this is giving current position of cursor. then I tried following code

```
MouseEventArgs m = (MouseEventArgs)e;
Xpos=m.X;
Ypos=m.Y;
```

but this position is not with respect to whole screen.

How I can get position of control in which click event is performed?

**edit**

As the link provided for duplicate ,,,,It provides position of point where click action is performed,,,,It does not provide the position of control in which click is performed.

Comment: Which event do you use to get `MouseEventArgs`?

Comment: Is it `WindowsForms` or `WPF` application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting The Location Of A Control Relative To The Entire Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998076/getting-the-location-of-a-control-relative-to-the-entire-screen)

Comment: do you want position with respect to primary screen or your window screen?

Comment: @ershoaib window screen

Comment: @dhilmathy : point will give the position where click is performed but I want control postion in which click is performed

Comment: Use ((Control)sender).Location to get the position of the control that was clicked.  Please edit your question to make it clear that this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is in `WindowsFormApplicaiton` then

If your control is `button` like in screen shot

[image]

Then you can access its location wrt to its primary screen also and form screen also

Below is the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This code gives you the location of button1 wrt your primary working screen
    Point location = this.PointToScreen(button1.Location);
    int x1 = location.X;
    int y1 = location.Y;

    MessageBox.Show($"X: {x1}, Y: {y1}");


    //This code gives you the location of button1 wrt your forms upper-left corner        
    Point relativeLoc = new Point(location.X - this.Location.X, location.Y - this.Location.Y);
    int x2 = relativeLoc.X;
    int y2 = relativeLoc.Y;

    MessageBox.Show($"X: {x2}, Y: {y2}");


    //This code gives you the location of button1 wrt your forms client area
    Point relativeLoc1 = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y);
    int x3 = relativeLoc1.X;
    int y3 = relativeLoc1.Y;

    MessageBox.Show($"X: {x3}, Y: {y3}");
}
```

In above code I used `this`, you can use any `forms` object instead as your need

**Edit:**

If you don't know where your control will be clicked then you have to register one event for all of your controls inside forms like

In below code i used `MouseHover` event but you can used any event as your need

First of all register `MouseHover` event for all of your controls inside `Form1_Load` like

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        c.MouseHover += myMouseHoverEvent;
}
```

Then your custom `MouseHover` event is

```
private void myMouseHoverEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = sender as Control;

    int x = control.Location.X;
    int y = control.Location.Y;

    MessageBox.Show($"X: {x}, Y: {y}");
}
```

Try once may it help you

Comment: @vk2s, please view the answer may it help you :)

Comment: here we know button1 is clicked,,,it may be clicked in any part of form...button1.Location

Comment: means do you need to know location of any control wrt mouse hover on form?

Comment: I want to know the position of control where click is performed,,,,and In which control click will be performed I dont know

Comment: vk2s, please view edit section in answer may it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? It should return what you're expecting (Left Top Point of the control you click).

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Text="Sample" Width="100" Height="50" 
           MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

**XAML.cs**

```
private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var control = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var positionToScreen = control.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Their is a button in form to close the form It throws execption "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Button'.'" in line var positionToScreen

Comment: @vk2s Are you closing the window on button click? Before that, is it `WindowsForms` or `WPF` application?

Comment: WindowsForms and yes closing on buttonclick

Comment: Try accessing the position before window is getting closed. If you can share your C# code part, it'll be easier for getting a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve your problem if you let this event handler handle the MouseClick event of all the controls you are interested in. 
If you want to include the position inside the clicked control. Then add the position included in the mouse event args (Se comment in code).

```
private void control_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        Control control = sender as Control;
        int posX = control.Location.X;
        int posY = control.Location.Y;
        //Add e.X respectivly e.Y if you want to add the mouse position within the control that generated the event.

        while (control.Parent != null)
        {
            control = control.Parent;
            posX += control.Location.X;
            posY += control.Location.Y;
        }

        ((Label)sender).Text = "X: " + posX + " Y: " + posY;
}
```

Comment: Only code snippets may answer the question. But providing an explanation is always welcomed in SO