# How to get the Textbox location from various TableLayoutPanel ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, textbox

I have four (4) TableLayoutPanels. And inside them I have some TextBoxes.
My intention is to display the Listview at downside of that Textbox.
Hence when I try to get the location of textbox which is inside the
tablelayout panel, its not giving proper X-Y... So how to get the correct location?

Comment: Maybe it will help you: [C# Get a control's position on a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478022/c-get-a-controls-position-on-a-form) 

`Point locationOnForm = control.FindForm().PointToClient(   control.Parent.PointToScreen(control.Location));`

Comment: Nice Answer...It simplified my 1/2 day try.

Answer (score 1):

`... its not giving proper X-Y ...`
Not really :

You can have multiple solutions :

1. Using the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which provides two values X and Y, the Location property gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control relative to the upper-left corner of its container :

**Location Property :**

```
int xLocation = textBox1.Location.X;
int yLocation = textBox1.Location.Y;
```

1. Using the [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.right%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bottom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties : they actually get the distance, in pixels, between the left (or top, right, bottom respectively) edge of the control and the top edge of its container's client area :

**Left, Top, Right Bottom :**

```
int leftLocation = textBox1.Left;
int topLocation = textBox1.Top;
int rightLocation = textBox1.Right;
int bottomLocation = textBox1.Bottom;
```

If you check the values of all these lines, you will find that left and top values are identical to the X and Y values of the Location property.

All these properties are there due to the inheritance from the [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, hence you will find them on any control deriving from that.

Hope this helps.