# how to get the location on a Control that is inside another control

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Get a control's position on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478022/c-get-a-controls-position-on-a-form)

C# Winforms: I have a big table layout that it has some panels inside it and they have some listboxes inside those panels with Dock->Fill, so if I say listbox.Top it will be Zero... but I want to know the location based on the X,Y of the Form or at least that tableLayout, How can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to consider the location from Parent Control.
 Control(X, Y) = ( UserControl.Location.X (@ Parent Control) + Control.Location.X (@ UserControl) , 
UserControl.Location.Y (@ Parent Control) + Control.Location.Y (@ UserControl) )

X = UserControl.Location.X (@ Parent Control) + Control.Location.X (@ UserControl) 
Y = UserControl.Location.Y (@ Parent Control) + Control.Location.Y (@ UserControl)