# find the position of button control inside the user control inside flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, button, user-controls, position, flowlayoutpanel

I have 20 usercontrols in the flowlayoutpanel in a windows form.

Each of the user control has a button.

I want to find the position of each button on the flowlayoutpanel. How can I find the X and Y coordinates for the buttons?

I can access the buttons like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.pnlContainer.Controls.Find("btnPrint",true))
{
    Button c = ctrl as Button;
    if (c != null)
    {
        logger.Info("x: "+c.Location.X + ",y: "+c.Location.Y,c);
    }
}
```

However, the x and y coordinates are always the same.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if the button is in the same location in all the UC then the x y will be the same for all the buttons  in UC's ,
and the location you get is relative to the UC and not to the form .

i think you can find it here

[C# Get a control's position on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478022/c-sharp-get-a-controls-position-on-a-form)

try this code

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control item in ctrl.Controls.Find("button1", true))
                {
                    Point pointOnForm = new Point(0, 0);
                    Control Btn = item;
                    for (; Btn.Parent != null && Btn.Parent.GetType() != typeof(Form); Btn = Btn.Parent)
                    {
                        pointOnForm.Offset(Btn.Location);
                    }

                    //label2.Text += pointOnForm + ",";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. However, is there a way to get it relative to form?

Comment: I found that I was making a mistake. I had to create the form inside the project I required to access the controls for. Thanks anyway!